# java: to find a whole match of a pattern

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have function which finds a word in a lengthy String.

The line matches if the variable "v" containing the string between `<vocab></vocab>`

```
if(p.matches("\\W"+v+"\\W"))
```

i want that this line should match that v is a complete word between \n or \t or space and is NOT contained in another word.

This is my string :

```
<meta>
<vocab>called</vocab>
</meta>
<para>
called to-VP,Reid-NP,television cameras-NP
called to-VP,Reid-NP,one of-NP
one of-VP,Reid-NP,ornate rooms-NP
called to-VP,Reid-NP,Capitol-NP
called to-VP,Reid-NP,ceremony-NP
passed on-VP,last week-NP,spending bill-NP
passed on-VP,last week-NP,House-NP
passed on-VP,last week-NP,Senate-NP
officially complete-VP,ceremony-VP/NP,action-NP
called to-VP,television cameras-NP,one-NP
called in-VP,television cameras-NP,Capitol-NP
called for-VP,television cameras-NP,ceremony-NP
called-VP,Reid-NP,television cameras-NP
age-NP,last week-NP,event-num
</para>
```

Comment: I can't say your question is clearly expressed, can you rephrase and elaborate?

Comment: Not sure about your actual problem or question either, but as a small note: I'd use `\b` rather than `\W` to match word boundaries, because `\b` will also match the beginning or the end of the string (something not true for `\W`).

Comment: Found Answer...

if(p.matches(".*\\b"+t+"\\b.*"))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [**`Pattern.quote(regex)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) for your variable `v` since it can contain some regex meta characters. Also to make sure you match complete word use word boundaries. So your pattern will look like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(v) + "\\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex is:

```
if (p.matches("(?s).*\\b" + v + "\\b.*"))
```

There are some important points here:

- `(?s)` means "dot matches newline", so it will work with multi-line input
- Use the regex `\b`, which is a "word boundary"
- `String.matches()` must match the *whole* string to return true, hence the `.*` at either end so the *whole* string is matched